# Properties and Interfaces

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to declare a property as an interface collection of an interface, and I want to instanciate the explicit type later, in the constructor. Something like this.

```
Public Class LicenseFile
    Implements ILicenseFile

    Public Property Collection As IList(Of ILicenseFileDataNode)

    Public Sub New()
        Collection = New List(Of LicenseFileDataNode) 'here throws an exception.
    End Sub

End Class
```

Of course, LicenseFileDataNode Implements ILicenseFileDataNode

The unique line of the constructor launch an exception saying something like:

> "An object of the type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NtnAgent.LicenseFileDataNode]'
>   can't be converted to an object of the type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[NtnAgent.ILicenseFileDataNode]'.

In short, the question is "Why It Didn't work"? This is a simplified scenario, but It's easy to take a workarround, But I need understand the reason because It's fails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make it simpler to reason about. Let's say `IAnimal` is your interface, and `Animal` is your concrete type that implements `IAnimal`. Well, a `List<Animal>` is not a `IList<IAnimal>`. Why? Because a `List<Animal>` can accept instances of `Animal`, and a `IList<IAnimal>` can accept objects that implement `IAnimal`. Consider:

```
class Animal : IAnimal { }
class EvilAnimal : IAnimal { }
```

So if we could assign an instance of `List<Animal>` to a variable of type `IList<IAnimal>`, you could insert `EvilAnimal`s into your `List<Animal>`, and that is clearly absurd because an `EvilAnimal` is not an `Animal`.

Comment: +1. For further research, Google Covariance and Contravariance.

Comment: List is List<IAnimal> not List<Animal>, and you can add EvilAnimal to this list.

Comment: @Saeed: A `List<Animal>` is not a `List<IAnimal>` for the same reason. You can add `EvilAnimal` to `List<IAnimal>` but not to `List<Animal>`. The mapping `T -> List<T>` is not covariant in `T`.

Comment: @Jason, you changed the main problem of OP, OP has List<IAnimal> not List<Animal>, I'm saying this.

Comment: Public Property Collection As IList(Of ILicenseFileDataNode)

Comment: @Saeed: I have no idea what you're talking about. He has an `IList<IAnimal>` and he is trying to assign a `List<Animal>` to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
> "Why It Didn't work"?
```

because the element type of `IList(Of ILicenseFileDataNode)`
is diffenrent from the elementtype of `List(Of LicenseFileDataNode)`

example: if `LicenseFileDataNode` and `LicenseFileDataNodeMock` both implement `ILicenseFileDataNode`

then both can be added to `IList(Of ILicenseFileDataNode)` but `List(Of LicenseFileDataNode)` cannot 
contain `LicenseFileDataNodeMock` items.

Using `List(Of ILicenseFileDataNode)` should work as expected.

for more details see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)